Mover popup de un programa via powershell
Estoy intentando mover una ventana/popup de login de usuario de un programa el cuál se pega hacia el borde derecho cuando el equipo tiene más de una pantalla, en ocasiones se queda entre ambas pantallas y los usuarios indican que es bastante molesto.
Mi intento
He probado con el script realizado por josefz  Script de Josefz ,y hasta aquí bien, con el teams,bloc de notas, firefox... no tengo ningún problema en mover y modificar su tamaño. El script funciona cogiendo el nombre del proceso, en este caso el programa está desarrollado en java entonces selecciono el proceso "javaw" y nada.
El programa saca un popup de login (1) de usuario pero tiene detrás una ventana oculta de primeras y luego cuando selecciono de nuevo el icono en la barra de tareas aparece (2) que es la que sí que soy capaz de mover, pero el popup nada adjunto capturas.

Adjunto la línea de código que he añadido al final del script para realizar el movimiento/modificacion de la ventana dentro del propio script.
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*javaw*'} | Set-Window -X 400 -Y 200 -Height 800 -Width 1200

¿Como podría mover este popup?

Tu quieres obtener el popup pero Get-Process Obtiene los procesos que se están ejecutando en la computadora local.

@Jorgesys Sí sé que estoy trabajando con los procesos del ordenador, el problema es ese que no se como diferenciar el proceso que crea el programa en java , que yo creia que únicamente creaba el popup y que la ventana de fondo no existia, estoy intentando buscar una manera de sacar las ventanas activas/principales para poder seleccionar el popup pero esta complicado.

He trabajado muy pocas veces con la API de windows, solo para crear windows forms y muy simples, creo que se puede optimizar mucho el script, pero funciona, he creado una tarea programada que arranca al iniciar la aplicación y realiza el cambio de posición.
#LE DOY TIEMPO PARA QUE CARGUE/APAREZCA LA VENTANA DEL PROGRAMA
Start-Sleep -Seconds 8
Add-Type @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

public class User32 {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

    public static string GetActiveWindowTitle() {
        IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(256);
        if (GetWindowText(handle, buffer, buffer.Capacity) > 0) {
            return buffer.ToString();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
"@
#NOMBRE DE LA VENTANA ACTIVA
$titventactiv = [User32]::GetActiveWindowTitle()
#$titventactiv

if ($titventactiv -eq "XYZ"){
Write-Host "El programa XYZ esta funcionando y está activo"
# CLASE DE WINDOWWS PARA MOVER LA VENTANA 
Add-Type @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Window {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public extern static bool MoveWindow(IntPtr handle, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool redraw);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr handle, int state);
}

public struct RECT {
    public int Left;        
    public int Top;         
    public int Right;       
    public int Bottom;      
}
"@

Function Set-ActiveWindowPosition {
    Param (
        [int]$X,
        [int]$Y,
        [int]$Width,
        [int]$Height
    )
    
    # Nom de la ventana activa no vale el del proceso
    $nomventactiv = [User32]::GetForegroundWindow()

    # SACO LAS COORDENADAS DE LA VENTAN EN SU POSICION ACTUAL
    $rectangulo = New-Object RECT
    $Return = [Window]::GetWindowRect($nomventactiv, [ref]$rectangulo)

    If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('X')) {
        $X = $rectangulo.Left            
    }
    If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Y')) {
        $Y = $rectangulo.Top
    }
    If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Width')) {
        $Width = $rectangulo.Right - $rectangulo.Left
    }
    If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Height')) {
        $Height = $rectangulo.Bottom - $rectangulo.Top
    }

    # OPCIONES DEL EL MOVIMIENTO DE LA VENTANA
    [Window]::MoveWindow($nomventactiv, $X, $Y, $Width, $Height, $True)
}

#Set-ActiveWindowPosition -X 100 -Y 100 -Width 800 -Height 600
Set-ActiveWindowPosition -X 750 -Y 400

}
else{
Write-Host "No se encuentra la ventana activa del programa (XYZ), HASTA LUEGO"
}

